# Iterate in a list that contain tuples and int in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

So I have created this list :

```
l = [(1,2,3),(4,5),6]
```

But when I do this :

```
for i in l:
    print (i[0])
```

It send me this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

So I want to know if you there is a method to print the number if it's an `int` or the first element if it is a `tuple`...

I hope I made it clear for you, do not hesitate to ask if you don't understand.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
l = [(1,2,3),(4,5),6]
for i in l:
    if isinstance(i,int):
        print(i)
    elif isinstance(i,tuple):
        print(i[0])
# 1
# 4
# 6
```

Using list comprehension, output as a form of list:

```
[i if isinstance(i,int) else i[0] for i in l]
# [1, 4, 6]
```

Comment: yeah just print(i if isinstance(i, int) else i[0])

Comment: @OlivierMelançon In short can you tell me the advantage of using `isinstance` over direct comp.

Comment: @meW It's not "better" per se, but it accounts for inheritance and is more versatile  in some specific situations.

Answer (score 3):

To support other data types (floats instead of ints, lists instead of tuples):

```
for i in l:
    try:
        print(i[0])
    except TypeError:
        print(i)
```

Note that this won't work if you want to print all chars of a string.

Comment: "Easier to ask forgiveness than permission" (`try`... `except`) is usually more Pythonic than `if`...`else`.

Comment: while beyond the scope of the question, it should be noted that if  `i` is of type `str`, the first character of the `i` will be printed, not all of `i`. e.g. `i == '90'` will give `9` not `90`

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to be safe and print the first item of the iterable you can apply subscripts, `hasattr` checks whether the Python object has a certain method where `__getitem__` is the equivalent of a slice function:

```
l = [(1,2,3),[4,5],6]

for i in l:
    if hasattr(i, '__getitem__'):
        print(i[0])
    else:
        print(i)

>> 1
4
6
```

This makes sure that you can always select an index from the sequence, given the types `list` or `tuples`. Note that an `str` type is also a sequence which is iterable. If you would want to exclude them, you can use `isinstance` to check the type of object, in this example we are checking for `not str` and `is Iterable`:

```
import collections

for i in l:
    if not isinstance(i, str) and isinstance(i, collections.Iterable):
        print(i[0])
    else:
        print(i)
```